# Considerations for using smaller diameter blades on table saw?

Tags: table-saw, saw-blade

I need a 1/16" kerf for a project.  All the 10" blades I can find that thin are into hundreds of dollars.

Meanwhile, I see thin-kerf 7.25" Freud Diablo blades selling for [under $15](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008WQ2H).  These say they're rated for 10,000 rpm.  (My saw says no-load speed is 4,800 rpm.)

I don't need to make deep cuts, nor am I doing high volume.  So other than reduced cut depth, and heat concerns with extended cutting, is there any reason not to put one of these smaller-diameter blades in my 10" table saw?

Comment: I can't think of any reason this wouldn't work but one of the power-tool experts should weigh in on this. One must I'd say though — make a new zero-clearance insert for the 7.25" blade.

Comment: matthias wandel does this all the time... see woodgears.ca.

Comment: If you have a riving knife, you will need to remove it, as it will be too thick for the kirf of the blade, and will also be too far from the blade to be effective.

Answer (score 16):

I use 7.25" and 8" blades on a 10" table saw all the time, with no problem. You will have less depth of cut, of course, and also a reduction of rim speed,which will slightly increase chances of tearout, and slightly reduce risk of burning, both to a negligible degree under most conditions. Go for it.

Comment: Interestingly, I just watched a YT video yesterday from a guy who claimed he just found his new "miracle" blade for his table saw - a 7-1/4" Freud Diablo from HD. He claimed that it cut smoother than his $150+ Forrest with a stabilizer disk. He said he was able to make perfect glue-up joints right off the table saw. No mention of increased tearout or burning. Go for it, indeed!

Answer (score 13):

It's common to use 8" dado sets on 10" table saws.

The main disadvantage of a smaller blade is simply that your maximum cut depth is reduced.

There is also going to be a reduction in the speed at which the teeth meet the wood, and increase in torque. (Circumference is pi*diameter, so this is linear with blade size for a given RPM). That may affect cutting behavior, but I'm not sure what the effects might be.

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing through cuts, your table saw's stock riving knife will not be close enough to the back side of the blade to prevent kickback.  To address this, you can create a custom throat plate with an appropriately-sized and -located  splitter.

Answer (score 5):

To add to rob's answer, it is unlikely that your saw's factory riving knife/splitter will be thin enough to pass through the smaller kerf. This may require you to remove the splitter or purchase/make one that will work safely with the blade kerf and diameter you are considering.

If, however, your saw is not currently equipped with that safety measure, nothing really changes by moving to a thinner blade.

Answer (score 2):

Another advantage to using smaller blades is when cutting custom moldings from preferred stock, particularly cove moldings. You can dial in a smaller radius to create very distinct molding.